# Get process ID by name

Tags: c++, linux, process

I'd like to get a process ID given its name under Linux.

Is there a simple way to do this ?

I haven't found anything on C++ that could be easily usable !

Comment: Depends on your definition of "easily usable".

Comment: What if there is more than one instance of the executable running?

Comment: You could always look at the sources of `ps`, `top` (to see where they get their process lists) or even better, `killall` (to see how that looks up PIDs for the name you give it).

Comment: Yes, it's quite simple: just scan `/proc/XXX/` where `XXX` are all PID's. How to do it you can see in sources of `pgrep`. I did something like that in my daemons (to be sure that the daemon running single).

Comment: Can you exec `pidof`? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pidof

Answer (score 9):

If going for 'easily usable',

```
char buf[512];
FILE *cmd_pipe = popen("pidof -s process_name", "r");

fgets(buf, 512, cmd_pipe);
pid_t pid = strtoul(buf, NULL, 10);

pclose( cmd_pipe );
```

is the way to go.

Yeah, it's ugly, I know. It's much better to go and read pidof source code.

Comment: Well ... I can't use that in a C++ program, can I ?

Comment: what was wrong with your initial answer? This is now ugly C code (withdrew my upvote).

Comment: What was wrong is the fact that pidof doesn't return the pid, it **prints** the pid to standard output (and returns 0 on success).

Comment: @MikeTelson, you can use it, why not? The right way to do this is, of course, by reading proc (which one can learn from [pidof source code](http://code.google.com/p/secured/source/browse/src/pidof.c?spec=svnd53f28f2475e9a969735475ae95d1e217e40a66e&r=d53f28f2475e9a969735475ae95d1e217e40a66e). But it's definitely **not** 'easily usable'.

Comment: Yeah I can ! It didn't understood it with the first version of that answer but with the full code now I understand. Thanks ! (when I got 15 reputation i'll upvote)